# Springer Journal template - override bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

****Update:** question is answered in the comment. Please close the question.**

I am preparing a journal article for Springer who asked me to use a template like this: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-general-template-file-for-the-latex-package-svjour3-for-springer-journals/pbbwqhxxvtbp

I have imported it and created a project that is publicly available here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tzjmmnpddkwx

However, this template has a flaw with the bibliography format and the edtiorial office is aware of that. They told me that they are 'working on it' but I am not satisfied with waiting for an answer. After all the problem seems to have existed for a while. So I am asking for help here.

The problem seems to happen whenever I want to use external bibliography file and use an existing style file to format them. If you use `\bibitem` to add each reference entry and cite them, it looks ok, such as lines 173-175:

```
\bibitem{RefJ}
% Format for Journal Reference
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
```

But when I use the following command to import references, the code compiles but the format of the references and citation is very messy (lines 181 - 183)

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{lrec2016}
\bibliography{lre2021}
```

And this is what the resulting citation and bibliography looks like:

[image]
[image]

Especially when the author name list is long, it looks extremely ugly. The format also appears different from the official journal such as https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10579-020-09488-3. As you can see from my code above, I also tried to import a different biliography style file (lrec2016), but that does not change anything at all.

Please can I get some tips on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: In the banner of the file `spbasic.bst`, one finds the following statement: "For use with the `natbib` package". Hence the following question: Have you tried loading the `natbib` citation management package?

Comment: Incidentally, when I click on the link you provided to a webpage on overleaf, I get the following message: "Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page."

Comment: @Mico thanks that sorted the problem. Apologies for my lack of latex knowledge, I have been always copied existing templates before and had little idea that you needed to load a package to manage this. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the main issue was solved in the comments.

Comment: Not sure if I can 'close' it but I Can delete it, but want to make sure that does not lose your credits

Comment: Don't delete the posting! The question was a good one.